# Can I store data into HBase and use Titan to load the data

Tags: hbase, titan

I have read many docs on the use of Titan and HBase, most cases were using Titan to establish a graph and upload it to the HBase storage backend. However, I am wondering if there is any way to firstly store data into HBase and use Titan to load the data into graph type?

Comment: You Need to Read [How to Ask a Query on Stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you for your kind remind, I'll read it.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible. Titan has it's own [data model](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/data-model.html) which the data must conform to.

So if you have some generic data stored in HBase it would still need to undergo some migration process to conform to the model and be usable by Titan.